# How can I calculate this sum $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x^2\cdot q^{x-1} \cdot p$?

Tags: summation

How can I calculate this sum (while $0 < q,\ p < 1$)?

$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty} x^2\cdot q^{x-1} \cdot p$$

I thought to calculate it with the derivative of something that gives $x^2\cdot q^{x-1} \cdot p$, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Take derivative of $\frac{p}{1-q}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} q^x\cdot p$ with respect to $q$. Then multiply by $q$, and finally take another derivative with respect to $q$

Comment: @totoro It's not so clear, can you explain more?

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593996/how-to-prove-sum-n-0-infty-fracn22n-6, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1969933/how-can-i-find-a-closed-form-for-this-partial-sum-sum-n-1k-fracn33n

Comment: Take responsibility for your own shortcomings. It is very clear, while it is you who doesn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to proceed.

Let $D$ be the differential operator ($Df = f'$). Then,
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k^2 q^{k - 1} = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{k = 1}^\infty (qD)^2 q^k = \frac{1}{q} (qD)^2 \sum_{k = 1}^\infty q^k.
\end{equation}
This last sum is geometric. Carrying out the (somewhat tedious) calculations
yields:
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{1}{q} (qD)^2 \frac{q}{1 - q} = -\frac{q + 1}{(q - 1)^3}.
\end{equation*}
Multiplying by an arbitrary constant $p$ will not change the result.